# Class not declared in this scope (c++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a sort of banking game in c++ (text only). However, I am having a problem when trying to call a class from my `int main()`. It is giving me these two errors:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:31:3: error: 'Vaults' was not declared in this scope
   Vaults open;
   ^~~~~~
main.cpp:31:3: note: suggested alternative: 'puts'
   Vaults open;
   ^~~~~~
   puts

exit status 1
```

I am new at this, and still learning, so any help would be appreciated:

My C++ Code:

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Bank{
  public:
    string getName(string) {
    string name;
    return name;
   }
class Vaults{
  public:



  string openVault(string) { //alows user to open a vault
    string vault_number;
    return vault_number;
  }
};
};





int main(){
  //name of bank
  Bank get;
  Vaults get;
  string bankName;
  cout << "What is the name of your bank? : ";
  cin >> bankName;
  string getName("bankName");
  //end of name of bank

  //not working ???

  string vault_number;
  cout << "Which vault do you want to open?" << endl;
  cin >> vault_number;
  string openVault("vault_number");



}
```

Comment: If you fix your indentation, you will see that `Vaults` is declared inside of `Bank`. So there is no `Vaults` at the top level, only a `Bank::Vaults`.

Comment: `Vaults` is a nested class in `Banks`, you need to reference that.

Comment: I was trying to create a main class `bank` all of the things the bank contains as classes contained inside one large class. Will that not work?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking and your code makes no sense.

Comment: It's probably not a good design, but of course it will work, **if** you qualify the names properly as has already been explained.

Comment: "Bank get;
  Vaults get;" - notice anything wrong there? What is `get` supposed to be? A `Bank` or a `Vaults`?

Answer (score 4):

You have `Vaults` as an inner class of `Banks`.Since `vaults` is public inside `Banks` you can create an object of `Vaults` like

```
Banks::Vaults get;
```

If creating an inner class was not intended, you are better off moving `Vaults` as a separate class, then you would be able to create the object just like you did for `Bank`.

EDIT:If your objective was to create a main class bank and all of the things the bank contains inside it, you should read about [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Comment: But not with that name. There already is a local variable called `get`.

Comment: when looking at the rest of OPs code I have some doubts whether this answer alone will help....